# Pandas - Change value in column based on its relationship with another column

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am working with the [sklearn.datasets.fetch_20newsgroups()](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.fetch_20newsgroups.html) dataset. Here, there are some documents that belong to more than one news group. I want to treat those documents as two different entities that each belong to one news group. To do this, I've brought the document IDs and group names into a dataframe.

```
import sklearn
from sklearn import datasets
data = datasets.fetch_20newsgroups()

filepaths = data.filenames.astype(str)
keys = []
for path in filepaths:
    keys.append(os.path.split(path)[1])

groups = pd.DataFrame(keys, columns = ['Document_ID'])
groups['Group'] = data.target
groups.head()

>>  Document_ID Group
 0   102994      7
 1   51861       4
 2   51879       4
 3   38242       1
 4   60880       14

print (len(groups))
>>11314
print (len(groups['Document_ID'].drop_duplicates()))
>>9840
print (len(groups['Group'].drop_duplicates()))
>>20
```

For each Document_ID, I want to change its value if it has more than one Group number assigned. Example,

```
groups[groups['Document_ID']=='76139']

>>  Document_ID Group
5392    76139   6
5680    76139   17
```

I want this to become:

```
>>  Document_ID Group
5392    76139   6
5680    12345   17
```

Here, 12345 is a random new ID that is not already in `keys` list.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all the rows that contain duplicate `Document_ID` after the first with the `duplicated` methdod.  Then create a list of new id's beginning with one more than the max id. Use the `loc` indexing operator to overwrite the duplicate keys with the new ids.

```
groups['Document_ID'] = groups['Document_ID'].astype(int)
dupes = groups.Document_ID.duplicated(keep='first')
max_id = groups.Document_ID.max() + 1
new_id = range(max_id, max_id + dupes.sum())
groups.loc[dupes, 'Document_ID'] = new_id
```

Test case

```
groups.loc[[5392,5680]]

      Document_ID  Group
5392        76139      6
5680       179489     17
```

Ensure that no duplicates remain.

```
groups.Document_ID.duplicated(keep='first').any()
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Kinda Hacky, but why not!

```
data = {"Document_ID": [102994,51861,51879,38242,60880,76139,76139],
    "Group": [7,1,3,4,4,6,17],
   }
 groups = pd.DataFrame(data)

 groupDict ={}
 tempLst=[]

 #Create a list of unique ID's
 DocList = groups['Document_ID'].unique()
 DocList.tolist()

 #Build a dictionary and push all group ids to the correct doc id
 DocDict = {}
 for x in DocList:
     DocDict[x] = []

 for index, row in groups.iterrows():
     DocDict[row['Document_ID']].append(row['Group'])
 #For all doc Id's with multip entries create a new id with the group id as a decimal point.
 groups['DupID'] = groups['Document_ID'].apply(lambda x: len(DocDict[x]))
 groups["Document_ID"] = np.where(groups['DupID'] > 1, groups["Document_ID"] + groups["Group"]/10,groups["Document_ID"])
```

Hope that helps...